# MSBuild C++: configure TLB lookup paths

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, msbuild

The problem:
COM plugin to application, in C++. Uses set of TLBs provided by application to access all needed interfaces. TLBs are referenced via #import, and reside in repository's subdirectory. The final aim is to compile plugin without host application. But Visual C++ compiler doesn't want to search for transitively referenced TLBs in the same folder as the initial TLB being imported - due to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx#Anchor_2

I don't want to add special batch which would configure PATH and then open solution.

I consider adding proxy header to the TLBs folder as the last resort workaround.

The question:
Is there some way to instruct MSBuild so that it will modify PATH when running C++ compiler (best) or during opening solution (worse but acceptable)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the whole problem can be workarounded with three particular tweaks:

1. Import transitively imported TLBs before dependent ones
2. Use double quotes to wrap TLB names (extends lookup rules)
3. Use `no_registry` attribute, which seems to ensure lookup of transitive dependencies on disk.